# Django Query from given object instance

Tags: python, django-queryset

I was wondering if I could make a query based on a given object instance. 
For example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

author1 = Author()
author1.name = 'Guy'
author1.email = 'guy@gmail.com'
# Imagine that author AAA with 1q2w2e@gmail.com already exist

author2 = Author.objects.get(author1)  # Does it work?

author2 = Author.objects.get(name=author1.name,   # I know this one works
                             email=author1.email) # but if I have 30 fields, 
                                                  # it doesn't seen a nice option
```

Is there any way to get `author2` based on `author1` instance?

I have googled and I couldn't find anything. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/) doesn't show any light on that for me. Cheers!

Comment: Based on your edit, there's kind of no reason to do a lookup of every field on a model. If you do that, that's the same as doing a lookup on the primary key, as the answers below show. So, if you want to query based on a subset of fields, there's no general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Author.objects.get(pk=author1.pk)
```

Assuming that you want to look up the author with the same primary key. It'd just return itself. Querying foreign key fields with an instance simply queries on the primary key, so the above is roughly equivalent to the foreign key case.

Edit:

If you really really want to query based on every field name (I can't think of a use case though), you can use the [Meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/):

```
Author.objects.get(
    **{field.name: getattr(author1, field.name) 
       for field in author1._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False)}
)
```

Comment: Hey @Josh Smeaton I edited my question to be more clear about it. I was wondering if I don't know the "guy" pk.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Cheers @Josh Smeaton

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure. Just type:

```
author2 = Author.objects.get(pk=author1.id)
```

If you actuall want to have a copy of the author1 object, you could do something like this:

```
author2 = Author.objects.get(pk=author1.id)
author2.pk = None
author2.save()
```

This will create a new author object based on you author1

Comment: Hey @Remi if my model has 30 fields, I will use each field?

Comment: You only wanted to get the object? Or did you want to copy it to a new object?

Comment: Only to get the object. I edited my question. I tried to be more clear about it.

Comment: You only need to put in the id/pk. This one is unique through your database... Get will work if the field you are filtering for is unique.

Comment: in this case I don't have a id/pk because I created a new object without saving it. I appreciate your attention.